# Bulk index in elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch

I have to index a JSON array into elastic-search index. I am using javascript client to index the data.

I looped the array and indexed as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++ ) {
    client.create({  
        index: "name",
        type: "rrrrr",  
        body: rawData[i]
    }, function(error, response){
    });
}
```

I need to avoid the loop. SO i decided to go for "BULK API"

I referred https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html , in that for every document we have to specify headers as follows:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
```

But in the JSON array what i have will not contain this header. So anyway i have to loop here also. Without loop how can i achieve this.Please share your ideas.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to avoid the loop? Do you mean avoid making potentially hundreds of `create` calls or simply avoid looping over all your `rawData` elements?

Comment: @Val Thanks for your valuable time. Trying to avoid as many as loops in my program so that code is effective..

Comment: Can you show in the question how you create the `rawData` array?

Comment: @Val Its just a mongoDB collection Array.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** The BULK API will not help you with this.

The BULK API is not meant to reduce the number of loops your code may need to perform to format the data correctly - it exists to reduce data transfer between the client and the ES cluster. Instead of **1 call** (from client, to server) **per record** to index, the Bulk API allows you to do **1 call** for **N records** which results in faster indexing on the cluster side but also for a much faster execution time on the client-side.

That said, for the specific fields you mention, the BULK API does allow you to avoid specifying this for each and every record you want to bulk index. When using the PHP API, you can set the `index` and `type` once and then loop on your raw data only. Here's a code snippet using the Elasticsearch PHP API:

```
$esclient = // Set up an ES client here
$joined = '';
foreach($data as $q) {
    $joined .= json_encode($q) . "\n";
}

$all_es_params = array();
$all_es_params['body'] = <<<EOT
$joined

EOT;

// Assumes all documents will be put in the same index
$all_es_params['index']     = 'YOUR_INDEX_NAME';

// Assumes all documents have same type in your bulk call
$all_es_params['type']      = 'YOU_DOCUMENT_TYPE';

try {
    // Call ES BULK API
    $ret = $esclient->bulk($all_es_params);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Something went wrong
}
```

In the example above:

- `$data` is an array formatted for the Bulk API containing one record
  to index.
- A loop on the data is done to merge all records into one `body` value.
- The Bulk call is set up to specify the `index` and `type` values (instead of putting this data in each and every `$data` element).
- Finally, the Bulk API is called and will return a response with any potential errors.